# Auto print without dialogue box in php

Tags: php, printing, auto

I have used `window.print();` showing print dialogue box. Need to print without dialogue box on default printer code in php.

Comment: PHP is a server-side language and knows __nothing__ about printers.

Comment: help me to print directly without print dialogue box

Comment: `print` request requires more details. Where is the printing destination (screen, printer, plotter, file), what kind of data print (graphics, text, binary, image).

Comment: printing destination : printer, data print :text

Answer (score 0):

"window.print();" is a Javascript Command, so it executes in a user browser and no one browser allows to print without dialogue box and it is right (in other case "bad" web-sites will spam you on your printer).

If you are owner of the computer you want to print from, you can use any 3rd part library to print without preview.